# regex to remove special characters, spaces and number if first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex in javascript to remove special characters, spaces and numbers but only if its the first character.

For example the strings below

```
1 step for man & 2 steps for others 123!
step for 1 man & 2 steps for others 123!
```

I want it to render like so

```
stepforman2stepsforothers123
stepfor1man2stepsforothers123
```

I've been rattling my brain but cant seem to get the correct regex.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following regular expression:

```
/^\d+|[\W_]+/g
```

- `^\d+`: to match leading digits (Use `^\d` if you want to remove only one leading digit)
- `\W`: to match non word character (reverse of `\w`: `\w` matches digit/alphabet/`_`)
- `[\W_]`: to include `_` because `\W` does not include `_`

---

```
'1 step for man & 2 steps for others 123!'.replace(/^\d+|[\W_]+/g, '')
# => "stepforman2stepsforothers123"
'step for 1 man & 2 steps for others 123!'.replace(/^\d+|[\W_]+/g, '')
# => "stepfor1man2stepsforothers123"
```

Comment: Cheers, that is spot on!!